# Conditional multivariate distribution

Tags: multivariate-analysis, multivariate-normal-distribution

Suppose, Y = X + error where error follows standard normal(multivariate). Can we find the conditional distribution P(Y|X) if we don't know the distribution of X. If yes, how to start the procedure? Is it also going to follow normal distribution?

Comment: You told us the answer at the outset: the conditional distribution is the distribution of "error" itself, to which $X$ (a conditional *constant*) has been added.  There doesn't seem to be anything that needs to be said in reply!  Are you sure you have phrased your question as intended?

Comment: "the conditional distribution is the distribution of "error" itself" what does it mean? I believe that I phrase correctly. I just have a guess that the conditional distribution might follow normal too, but I am not sure and I don't know exactly how to start the procedure(if my guess is true)

Comment: you would need to know the value of  you're conditioning on. E(Y|X=x) tells you the mean of your conditional multivariate normal. Everything else follows from the statement about the error

Answer (score 1):

What @whuber was trying to say is that when you have a conditional probability p(Y|X=x) you treat X as a given i.e. a constant x (note small case x). So in that case, the only random variable there is, is the error~N(0, 1), so Y|x~N(x, 1). I hope that clarifies this

Comment: $y|x \sim \text{N} (x,1)$, not $(0,1)$.

Comment: You are absolutely right - my bad. Thanks, I'll get it fixed.